# How can I do to evaluate mean and std for a dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I am using pytorch and the dataset fashion MNIST but I do not know how can I do to evaluate the mean and the std for this dataset. Here is my code :

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch.nn.functional as F

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((mean), (std))])
batch_size = 32
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets.MNIST(
'../data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5):

Use this to calculate mean and std-

```
loader = data.DataLoader(dataset,
                         batch_size=10,
                         num_workers=0,
                         shuffle=False)

mean = 0.
std = 0.
for images, _ in loader:
    batch_samples = images.size(0) # batch size (the last batch can have smaller size!)
    images = images.view(batch_samples, images.size(1), -1)
    mean += images.mean(2).sum(0)
    std += images.std(2).sum(0)

mean /= len(loader.dataset)
std /= len(loader.dataset)
```